# How to hide upload button after file selected in antd upload component?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, next.js, antd

I want to hide file upload button after file get selected. and also want to show file upload progress bar with percentage. and after file get uploaded then need to show file preview.

I have tried with renderItem but didn't work any solution to hide upload button

Comment: why not give the  button after upload a class which is defined as display:none ?

Comment: @StefanBD yes, I tried its hiding file preview also after selecting a file. I want to show file preview, only need to hide the upload button

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide button after file is selected use **onChange** event of the file input to set the flieSelected State.

```
    class FileUpload extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fileSelected: false,
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ fileSelected: event.target.files.length > 0 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        {this.state.fileSelected ? null : <button>Upload</button>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then to show a progress bar progress of the file upload, you can use the progress event of the **XMLHttpRequest** object, which is used to perform the file upload.

```
 class FileUpload extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fileSelected: false,
    uploading: false,
    progress: 0,
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ fileSelected: event.target.files.length > 0 });
  }

  handleUpload = () => {
    this.setState({ uploading: true });

    const file = this.fileInput.files[0];
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", (event) => {
      if (event.lengthComputable) {
        const progress = Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total);
        this.setState({ progress });
      }
    });

    xhr.open("POST", "server/upload", true);
    xhr.send(file);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" ref={(input) => this.fileInput = input} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        {this.state.uploading ? (
          <div className="progress">
            <div
              className="progress-bar"
              style={{ width: `${this.state.progress}%` }}
            />
          </div>
        ) : this.state.fileSelected ? (
          <button onClick={this.handleUpload}>Upload</button>
        ) : (
          null
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is for the simple file-uploading tag. but I'm using antd upload component https://ant.design/components/upload this code is not applicable there